# CheckBox Controls in Repeater not maintaining state

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater

Bit confused about this. I was under the impression that if you added server controls to the ItemTemplate of a repeater then the ID's assigned to those controls would persist across postbacks and the state would be maintained. But it doesn't seem to be happening. Here's my ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidPending" runat="server" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>" />
<td class="leftpadd"><uc:restrictedtext ID="uclblCategory" runat="server" Width="125" /></td>
<td style="border-left:1px solid #528ABD;" class="leftpadd"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SelectedOptions")%></td>
<td style="border-left:1px solid #528ABD;" class="leftpadd"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price.IncludingTax", "{0:C}")%></td>
<td style="border-left:1px solid #528ABD;" class="leftpadd"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ExtrasCost", "{0:C}")%></td>
<td style="border-left:1px solid #528ABD;" class="leftpadd"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Quantity", "{0:000}")%></td>
<td style="border-left:1px solid #528ABD;" class="leftpadd"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkPendingItems" runat="server" /></td>
```

Which populates fine. What I'm looking to happen is for the user to be able to select certain items from the repeater using the checkbox and "process" them (i.e. perform some data operations on those items) on clicking a button which is outside the repeater. Here's my button click code:

```
Private Sub lnkPendingProcessSelected_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkPendingProcessSelected.Click
    For Each rItem As RepeaterItem In rptPendingItems.Items
        If rItem.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or rItem.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(rItem.FindControl("chkPendingItems"), CheckBox)
            If chk.Checked Then
                Dim orderItemId As Integer
                Dim hid As HiddenField = DirectCast(rItem.FindControl("hidPending"), HiddenField)
                orderItemId = CInt(hid.Value)
                My.Application.ManagerFactory.OrderManagerInstance.ChangeOrderItemStatus(orderItemId, Concrete.Cms.DataTransferObjects.OrderItemStatus.Processing)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But if you step through this, the checkboxes are found and assigned correctly but their Checked attribute is always False. Anyone have any suggestions as to why state isn't being maintained and what I can do about it?

Comment: Are you binding the repeater on postbacks as well?

Comment: Yep. Every Page_Load. I think I may need to use some javascript to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: why exactly to you databind on every page_load? my "flow" in this area: first-request databind, receive postback, process the received checkboxes, and after that i can bind the checkboxes. otherwise there will be e.g. a problem if a checkox-value is not present anymore in your datasource ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on CyberDude's comment, you're probably reseting the values when you databind. If possibly, try using IsPostback to only databind on the first page load.

**C#**

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    rptPendingItems.DataBind();
}
```

**VB**

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
  rptPendingItems.DataBind()
End If
```

If that's not possible, or doesn't work, you'll probably have to get and set all of those checkbox values mannually, and persist them against your data set, or in session or summat.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I do need to do it on every page_load as the values will have changed on postback. I got round it by using javascript to store the checked values in a hidden field control with a function attached to the onclick event of the checkbox.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and using the postback check solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a repeater inside a user control on a page with other user controls which cause post backs.  In some cases, I wanted to rebind on postback so I created a bool property (IsDirty) on the page that I could set to true when I wanted to rebind the data on postback.  Then in my page_load, I checked if (!IsPostBack || IsDirty) before databinding.